# React how to prevent child from rendering until state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on navigation that shows the second tier once you click on the menu item.

I have approximately this code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentData:[]
    }
  }

initFirstTier(type){
    let url="";
    let self= this;
    if (type=="Closed-End"){
       url="{one url here}"
    }
    else {
      url={another url here}
    }


  fetch(url)
    .then(function(response){
      response.json().then(function(data){
        self.setState({currentData:data});
      })
    })
}

render(){
 return(
         <div>
              <ul>
                    <li onClick={() => {this.initFirstTier('Mutual Fund')}}>           
                      <a href="javascript:;">Mutual Fund</a>         
                    </li>          
                    <li onClick={() => {this.initFirstTier('VPS')}}>
                      <a href="javascript:;">VPS</a>           
                    </li>         
                    <li onClick={() => {this.initFirstTier('Closed-End')}}>             
                      <a href="javascript:;">Closed-End Fund</a>          
                    </li>                 
             </ul>

             {/* ********************Tier 1********************/}

          {this.state.currentData.length !==0 ? <FirstTier currentData = {this.state.currentData} /> : null}
     </div>
     )
     }
 }
```

Here's the problem I'm having. For example, If I click on "VPS" menu item, the parent component calls the api and sends data to the child component - works as expected. However, if next I click on "Closed-End", which calls a different api, I still get the console log with data from the VPS api call in the child component, which I'm not supposed to get. And then I get the console.log with correct data, but everything is already broken by the time I get the correct data. How do I prevent React from sending old data to the child? I need to send it only once the state has been updated with the new api call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. The `<FirstTier>` component is being updated when the state updates, and the state updates after the `fetch` triggered by the menu click completes... so the only potential I see for issues is some delayed, possibly out of order updating if you have a *really* bad internet connection and click multiple items in rapid succession. Otherwise, it's not clear how "everything" becomes "broken" due to what you show here.

Comment: May be you want to set `self.setState({currentData: []});` as blank `[]` before making the call and to API and then set it once API call returns.

Comment: Rikin, That worked! I don't know why I didn't think of it myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might introduce a loading state.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentData:[],
      loading: false
    }
  }

initFirstTier(type){
    let url="";
    let self= this;
    if (type=="Closed-End"){
       url="{one url here}"
    }
    else {
      url={another url here}
    }

  this.setState({loading: true});
  fetch(url)
    .then(function(response){
      response.json().then(function(data){
        self.setState({currentData:data, loading: false});
      })
    })
}

render(){
 return(
         <div>
              <ul>
                    <li onClick={() => {this.initFirstTier('Mutual Fund')}}>           
                      <a href="javascript:;">Mutual Fund</a>         
                    </li>          
                    <li onClick={() => {this.initFirstTier('VPS')}}>
                      <a href="javascript:;">VPS</a>           
                    </li>         
                    <li onClick={() => {this.initFirstTier('Closed-End')}}>             
                      <a href="javascript:;">Closed-End Fund</a>          
                    </li>                 
             </ul>

             {/* ********************Tier 1********************/}

          {this.state.currentData.length !==0 ? 
              (this.state.loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <FirstTier currentData = {this.state.currentData} />) 
              : null}
     </div>
     )
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure two type of url is enough in initFirstTier?